# Small and big background on ios app

Tags: ios, scroll, zooming

I am developing a board game with iOS, the board is viewed from a larger perspective on the screen with dimensions of 480 * 320, and looks over.
I had thought of that when you come to play the user is made a kind of zoom to where the player, I tested with a scrollview changing the image of a 480 * 320 960 * 640 but does not work well, too I tried to add a background of 960 * 640 and change the center property, but I do not work.
Anybody can give me some idea of ​​how to do it?
What do you use?
I also like that you could move around the board with your finger moving the background image, so I tried it with scrollview.
Anyway, what I try to do is that you can see the board in small and large but not me making him pixele zoom image in scrollview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're attempting to build is similar to how Apple implements the underpinnings for their UIImagePickerController when viewing the photo library. The appropriate way to handle this in a scroll view is to use the largest image possible (so 960x640, but anything larger with appropriate aspect ratio will work too).

You then set the initial content zoom factor  of the scroll view to properly fit the entire image on the screen. This will allow you to zoom in and out. I'd recommend watching all 5 years worth of WWDC videos on scroll views (5 videos as of WWDC 2013). They are all excellent and constantly showing new and interesting ways to use scroll views, since most of iOS utilizes them in some fashion.

Also, Ray Wenderlich's site has a decent tutorial for beginners on scroll views here:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content